# How can i prove this? (Statistics, converges in d)

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, convergence-divergence

Here is questions

Q.Consider a sequence of Poisson random variables ${X_n}$ ~ $Poisson(\lambda_n)$ $(\lambda_n>0)$

when $\lambda_n$ be any positive real sequence(not integer), Prove the following statement:
$\frac{X_n - \lambda_n}{\sqrt{\lambda_n}}$ $->N(0,1)$ (converges in distribution) as $\lambda_n \to \infty$.

When $\lambda_n$ is integer i can decompose $X_n$ bout poisson(1) but i can't (since the condition about $\lambda_n$)

Hint for this question(i received) -> Slutsky's theorem. How can i solve this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Apart from Slutsky's theorem you should use central limit theorem and infinite divisibility of Poisson distribution

Comment: Just look at the mgf, it should converge, no?